# Somebody can explain for me this code? (having issues in while)

Tags: java

while (y < n) , so to enter in while loop, y should be bigger than n, but why if i put any number in n, it's entering in while loop, it shouldn't if i put a number bigger than y, right?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n =24;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    while (y < n)
    {
        if (n % y == 0)
        {
            n = n / y;
            x++;
        }
        else y++;
   }
    System.out.println(x + " " + n);



}
```

Comment: "so to enter in while loop, y should be bigger than n" is false. It should be smaller.

Comment: "it shouldn't if i put a number bigger than y, right?" - no, it's the other way round. It won't enter the loop if `n` is less than or equal to `y`

Comment: no his logic is correct, he is saying while **y** is LESS than **n**, enter the loop, y = 2 and n = 24, you guys are overthinking it

Comment: The main problem if that i change the variable n number and put number lower than y, it is entering while loop also and giving me answers out of nowhere @jonskeet

Comment: so lets say the loop is still executing if lets say y=25 and n=24?

Comment: but sir, in while loop, to enter the loop, it should be contradicted with condition right? so y should be bigger than n. Im confused cause we learned while loop, and when im trying it, on other code but the same idea, it re-ask me to enter a number each time i put a wrong condition. @ProgrammingNewb

Comment: yes sir, the output would be 1 24 why? @ProgrammingNewb

Comment: @RaphaelEid: No, that really won't happen. For example, compile and run this code: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/f386552fc3c9fa5c5cdfa27b90ed4677 - it won't print "In while loop".

Comment: id have to run the code and see why, because it seems like n is always changing

Comment: "but sir, in while loop, to enter the loop, it should be contradicted with condition right? so y should be bigger than n" - no, that's the exact opposite of what a while loop does. A while loop will only execute when the condition *is* satisfied. If `y` is bigger than `n`, the loop won't execute.

Comment: @jonskeet yeah i got it, i runned your code and i saw the difference, but here like :
`int x,y;
        do {
        x = in.nextInt();
        y = in.nextInt();
        }
        
        while (x>y);
        {
           System.out.println("OKK");
           
        }`

im forced to put y bigger than x to enter while loop, thats why im confused

Comment: @JonSkeet and if we choose `n=24` , and `y=2`, and it entered the loop, now `(n % y == 0 )` is *true* so the new value of `n` would be `12` right? because of `n = n/y` and we put `x++` so the value of `x` would be `2` , why the output is giving `4` `3` ?

Comment: @RaphaelEid: We can only answer questions about the code you show us. If you actually want to ask about a `do/while` loop, that's what should be in your question. A normal `while` loop doesn't work quite the same. (`do/while` checks the condition at the *end* of each iteration, so there's always at least one iteration.)

Comment: @RaphaelEid: Because 12 is still greater than 2, so it's going through the loop again. (And then a third time.) Now would be a really good time to learn about using a debugger - and adding diagnostic logging - so you can get a better idea of what's going on

Comment: @JonSkeet so the `do/while` loop needs to be **contradicted** with the condition and the `while` loop alone need to be **true** with the condition right?

Comment: @jonSkeet sorry sir, im just new at java at dont have idea about all the functions, thank you for your time

Comment: At this stage, I would *strongly* recommend 1) reading a tutorial on debugging with whatever IDE you're using; 2) finding a good book or tutorial on Java. Stack Overflow is a great place for specific questions, but it's not a good way to learn the language from scratch, and it's definitely not a replacement for books. For while and do-while loops, read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Thank you sir !! i really thank you ! @JonSkeet